# Facebook OpenGraph Issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have done extensive searches on the Internet for a solution to this issue, but all that I can find is always related to making timeout adjustments on a Linux machine running Apache.  I am running IIS version 10 on Windows 2019 Server.  When Facebook changed it's website approximately 30-days ago, the Open Graph image sharing protocol stopped working properly.  An attempt to use the Facebook Developer scraper, I get the following timeout error.

```
Curl Timeout
The request to scrape the URL timed out.

Curl Error
Curl error: 28 (OPERATION_TIMEOUTED)
```

I also filed a bug report with Facebook, but they simply closed the report, stating that the problem is with my server or network connection.  I opened and inspected the server's error logs, and found no issues.  I then setup and inspected the IIS logs, and found that Facebook indeed hit the server properly and fetched an image and reported it back.  But the timeout error still occurs and the image is not shared upon an attempt to share it.  Here are the records from the IIS logs that seem to indicate that Facebook is indeed contacting my server correctly, except for the fact that they are using "http" rather than "https."  This has been reported to Facebook.

```
2020-12-24 18:31:51 W3SVC3 EDENUSA-FS11 10.1.252.250 GET /images/qr_code/edenusa_qr_code.png - 443 - 69.171.249.113 facebookexternalhit/1.1+(+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php) - www.edenusa.com 200 0 0 70

2020-12-24 18:32:02 W3SVC3 EDENUSA-FS11 10.1.252.250 GET /rent-lighting/lighting/rent_lighting.asp - 443 - 69.171.249.111 facebookexternalhit/1.1+(+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php) - www.edenusa.com 200 0 0 21410
```

And following is a snippet of the required meta code in our header area, from the home page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Rent a Stage | Rent a Sound System | Rent Lighting System | Rent Up Lighting</title>
<meta prefix="fb: https://ogp.me/ns/fb#" property="fb:app_id" content="1376081292633720">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.edenusa.com/index.asp" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Rent a Stage | Rent a Sound System | Rent Lighting System | Rent Up Lighting" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.edenusa.com/images/homepage/compressed/indian_temple_in_chino_hills.jpg" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1376081292633720" />
```

I've worked on this for over a week now, without resolution.  Anybody else having this issue, or know of a way to resolve the timeout issue?

Comment: Those URLs are not Facebook fetching https://www.edenusa.com/index.asp so Facebook have problem fetching index.asp. Your server is incredible slow when I go to that URL the first time. If I reload the page it goes fast. But the first time it takes over 20 seconds. https://imgur.com/a/iS01iU4

Comment: @WizKid: Thank you for your comment.  I am not sure what you mean by "Those URLs are not Facebook fetching edenusa.com/index.asp..."  Can you please explain a bit more what is meant by that?  And I will look into the slow load.  I've seen that a few times in the past, but thought that I had resolve it.

Comment: The 2 logs you showed is Facebook requesting `/images/qr_code/edenusa_qr_code.png` and `/rent-lighting/lighting/rent_lighting.asp`. When the debugger crawl `https://www.edenusa.com/index.asp` you should see a request to `/index.asp`

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved as follows:

1. We had to remove REST code in the GLOBAL.ASA that goes out and fetches geographic info (City and State only) based upon the client's IP address.  The service endpoint is a bit slow, and required that a longer timeout than might be considered "normal" to be used.  So when this code branch was commented out, the Facebook CURL timeout error no longer occurred.  We are looking at another IP geographic info service that is faster.
2. After completing step 1, we found that on the home page ONLY, we had to leave the INDEX.ASP portion of the URL in place.  We had code the stripped the "index.asp" off the canonical URL.  For unknown reason, Facebook looks at the HTTP header, sees that the original URL has the "index.asp" included, and then compares that to the URL specified in the "og:url" meta tag.

In conclusion, the most recent rollout of Facebook includes new code that configured a shorter timeout value for CURL.  This caused websites out on the web with a somewhat shorter startup time, to experience this issue.  So for now, the only fix is to monitor a site's startup time, and shorten it down enough for the Facebook debugger/scraper to function as it did before the most recent changes.